# How to create legend in Matlab when color is a variable in data

Tags: matlab, colors, legend, scatter-plot

I have three columns of data - the first column being a Class variable (Class 1, Class 2, Class 3). The other two columns will be used as x and y to be plotted on a scatterplot, where Class is differentiated by different colored points.

```
c=Class;   #colors are assigned automatically in scatter(x,y,c)
```

I can't figure out how to write the code for the legend to show that, for example, 'Class 1=red, Class 2=blue, Class 3=yellow'. I've tried

```
legend(Class)   #'Class' is the variable name in the data

legend('Class 1 = c(1)', 'Class 2 = c(2)', 'Class 3 = c(3)')
```

Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/62204-simplest-way-to-add-a-legend-to-the-groups-of-a-scatter-plot) seem useful

Comment: Thanks! This technically works but produces a lower quality graph, aesthetically - the colors revert to basic RGB; the legend shows only '1','2', and '3' next to each color; and the points were changed to squares.

Is there no way to create the legend I was trying to create using "scatter()" rather than "gscatter()", maintaining the colors and legend labels I would like to use?

Comment: What about the second answer there?

Comment: Maybe you can plot one column at the time. This will create 3 scatter objects, each with a set of points. Color can be set for each one of those.